# Filtrar tabla dentro de un intervalo de fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
   Fecha      Valor
2019-02-16  32400000
2019-02-17  18360000
2019-02-18  10800000
2019-02-19  10800000
```

Con esta consulta:

```
SELECT  
convert (VARCHAR(10),fechaInicioReporte,120) as fechaReporte,
SUM(DATEDIFF(millisecond, fechaInicioReporte, fechaFinReporte)) as tiempoSinConexion
FROM verificadorReporte 
GROUP BY convert (VARCHAR(10),fechaInicioReporte,120)
```

Quisiera hacer otra consulta con la cual pueda filtrar que me diera esos valores por ejemplo solo del 17 al 18 de febrero y me diera como resultado esto:

```
   Fecha      Valor
2019-02-17  18360000
2019-02-18  10800000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con un `where` y la consulta te quedaría algo como esto:

```
SELECT  
convert (VARCHAR(10),fechaInicioReporte,120) as fechaReporte,
SUM(DATEDIFF(millisecond, fechaInicioReporte, fechaFinReporte)) as tiempoSinConexion
FROM verificadorReporte 
where fechaInicioReporte >= '2019-02-17 00:00:00' AND fechaInicioReporte <= '2019-02-18 23:59:59'
GROUP BY convert (VARCHAR(10),fechaInicioReporte,120)
```

En este ejemplo te filtrará de 2019-02-17 00:00:00 a 2019-02-18 23:59:59, pero tu puedes elegir cualquier otro intervalo de fechas usando el mismo `WHERE`.